# Taking product content out of tabs in my theme

Tags: product, layout, product-view

I am attempting to remove some tabs from my theme product view so in Catalog.xml I have the following code:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>gallery</alias><title>Gallery</title><block>catalog/product_view_media</block><template>catalog/product/view/media.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Product Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review"><alias>product_review</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template></action>            
            </block>
```

I wish to replace this with:

```
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml"/>
```

Yet nothing is showing in my test environment. I will be attampting to do this via a local xml file eventually but have removed that level of abstraction for  now to try and get my thoughts around why the blocks are not showing. Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

change `product.info.media` to `product.info.media1` and also  `as="media"` to  `as="media1"`.

Also `name="product.description"` `as="description"` change to `name="product.description1"` `as="description1"`.

*Call this child block to  view.phtml by below code if those are view.phtml's child blocks*

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media1');?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('description1');?>
```